# Passar parâmetros PHP para JQuery Mobile Panel

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, get, panel

Bom dia a todos,

Estou tentando fazer uma função onde um JQM Panel recebe dinamicamente uma página em PHP com alguns parâmetros. Porém não funciona, o panel abre em branco. Segue abaixo o código que estou utilizando:

```
     $(".botao").on("mouseup", function (e) {
        var url = $.ajax({
                      method: "GET",
                      url: "menu.php",
                      data: { qtd: "1", linhas: "19" }
                    });     
        opendialog(url);
    });

    function opendialog(page) {
        $("#menu").html(page);
        $("#menu").trigger('updatelayout');
        $("#menu").trigger('create');
        $("#menu").panel("open");
    }
```

Já utilizei também o .GET ao invés do .AJAX no código, também sem sucesso.

Grato desde já pela ajuda.

Comment: Mano, não deveria ter o método `success` no `$.ajax` e a partir dele você chamaria a `opendialog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta fazer desta forma, assim você tem no success como atribuir o retorno da chamada ajax. Verifique com o comando console.log(retorno) o que vai retornar desta url que você esta acessando e realiza a atribuição aos elementos #id menu como desejar. Depois do retorno de success ele irá chamar a trigger e panel no complete. Caso ocorrer algum error na chamada ajax você pode tratar com o error.

```
 $(".botao").on("mouseup", function (e) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: "menu.php",
        method: "GET",
        data: { qtd: "1", linhas: "19" },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
           console.log("Trate o Error neste ponto!");
        },
        success: function(retorno) {
            console.log("se tiver duvida do que está retornando: " + retorno);
            $("#menu").html(retorno);                   
        },      
        complete: function(){
            $("#menu").trigger('updatelayout');
            $("#menu").trigger('create');
            $("#menu").panel("open");
        }
    });      
});
```

Comment: Deu certo Fernando, muito obrigado! Só mais uma dúvida, qual código seria o equivalente do "onclose" deste painel?